# asyncio.wait not returning on first exception

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have an AMQP publisher class with the following methods. `on_response` is the callback that is called when a consumer sends back a message to the RPC queue I setup. I.e. the `self.callback_queue.name` you see in the `reply_to` of the `Message`. `publish` publishes out to a direct exchange with a routing key that has multiple consumers (very similar to a fanout), and multiple responses come back. I create a number of futures equal to the number of responses I expect, and `asyncio.wait` for those futures to complete. As I get responses back on the queue and consume them, I set the result to the futures.

```py
    async def on_response(self, message: IncomingMessage):
        if message.correlation_id is None:
            logger.error(f"Bad message {message!r}")
            await message.ack()
            return
        body = message.body.decode('UTF-8')
        future = self.futures[message.correlation_id].pop()
        if hasattr(body, 'error'):
            future.set_execption(body)
        else:
            future.set_result(body)
        await message.ack()

    async def publish(self, routing_key, expected_response_count, msg, timeout=None, return_partial=False):
        if not self.connected:
            logger.info("Publisher not connected. Waiting to connect first.")
            await self.connect()
        
        correlation_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        futures = [self.loop.create_future() for _ in range(expected_response_count)]
        self.futures[correlation_id] = futures
        await self.exchange.publish(
            Message(
                str(msg).encode(),
                content_type="text/plain",
                correlation_id=correlation_id,
                reply_to=self.callback_queue.name,
            ),
            routing_key=routing_key,
        )
        done, pending = await asyncio.wait(futures, timeout=timeout, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_EXCEPTION)
        if not return_partial and pending:
            raise asyncio.TimeoutError(f'Failed to return all results for publish to {routing_key}')

        for f in pending:
            f.cancel()
        del self.futures[correlation_id]

        results = []
        for future in done:
            try:
                results.append(json.loads(future.result()))
            except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as e:
                logger.error(f'Client did not return JSON!! {e!r}')
                logger.info(future.result())
        return results
```

My goal is to either wait until all futures are finished, or a timeout occurs. This is all working nicely at the moment. What doesn't work, is when I added `return_when=asyncio.FIRST_EXCEPTION`, the `asyncio.wait..` does not finish after the first call of `future.set_exception(...)` as I thought it would.

What do I need to do with the future so that when I get a response back and see that an error occurred on the consumer side (before the timeout, or even other responses) the `await asyncio.wait` will no longer be blocking. I was looking at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) and it says:

> The function will return when any future finishes by raising an exception

when `return_when=asyncio.FIRST_EXCEPTION`. My first thought is that I'm not raising an exception in my future correctly, only, I'm having trouble finding out exactly how I should do that then. From the [API documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future) for the `Future` class, it looks like I'm doing the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

When I created a minimum viable example, I realized I was actually doing things MOSTLY right after all, and I glanced over other errors causing this not to work. Here is my minimum example:

The most important change I had to do was actually pass in an `Exception` object.. (subclass of `BaseException`) do the `set_exception` method.

```py
import asyncio

async def set_after(future, t, body, raise_exception):
    await asyncio.sleep(t)
    if raise_exception:
        future.set_exception(Exception("problem"))
    else:
        future.set_result(body)
    print(body)

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    futures = [loop.create_future() for _ in range(2)]
    asyncio.create_task(set_after(futures[0], 3, 'hello', raise_exception=True))
    asyncio.create_task(set_after(futures[1], 7, 'world', raise_exception=False))
    print(futures)
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait(futures, timeout=10, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_EXCEPTION)
    print(done)
    print(pending)


asyncio.run(main())
```

In this line of code `if hasattr(body, 'error'):`, body was a string. I thought it was JSON at that point already. Should have been using `"error" in body` as my condition in any case. whoops!